# Best way to accept command line inputs synchronously in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

What is the best way to accept a series of command line inputs in nodejs synchronously ?

like the program will print

```
Enter Value for variable one
```

then the user enters value, after that the command line should ask for second input like

```
Enter Value for variable two
```

and so on

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this, IMHO is showing "questions" to the user and waiting to his answers. Those questions can be always the same (a prompt like ">>") or maybe different (if you want to ask for some variables, for instance).

To show these questions you can use [stdio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stdio). It is a module that simplifies standard input/output management, and one of its main features is precisely what you want:

```
var stdio = require('stdio');
stdio.question('What is your name?', function (err, name) {
    stdio.question('Are you male or female?', ['male', 'female'], function (err, sex) {
        console.log('Your name is "%s". You are "%s"', name, sex);
    });
});
```

If you run the previous code you'll se something like this:

```
What is your name?: John
Are you male or female? [male/female]: female
Your name is "john". You are "female"
```

`stdio` includes support for retries if you specify a group of possible answers. Otherwise users will be able to write whatever they want.

PD: I'm the `stdio` creator. :-)

[image: NPM]
<sub>(source: [nodei.co](https://nodei.co/npm/stdio.png))</sub>

Comment: The question asked for a synchronous method, stdio uses callbacks for asynchronous execution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific needs, you could create your own REPL.

http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html

Just call `repl.start()` with options for `prompt`, and use your own custom `eval` and `writer` callbacks.

```
repl.start({
    prompt: 'Enter value: ',
    eval: function (cmd, context, filename, callback) {
         // Do something
        callback(/* return value goes here */); 
    },
    writer: function (data) {
        // echo out data to the console here
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Brad , thanks for the reply i am using the following and was not able to print data
var repl = require("repl");
repl.start({
    prompt: 'Enter value: ',
    eval: function (cmd, context, filename, callback) {
        callback(/* return value goes here */); 
    },
    writer: function (data) {
        console.log('data is '+data);
    }
});
but i am getting the data as undefined, also i was not able to understand what each option does in repl.start() is there a working demonstration for that somewhere ?

Comment: @nlingutla, You need to call the callback with data if you expect to get data available at your writer function.  If you accept input and no data is necessary, leave it undefined and change your writer function's output.  Descriptions of all of the options are at http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html.  Which options are you having trouble with?  I do not believe there is example code out there.  I figured it out just by messing with it.